# how to put values for columns for whome the NULL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am confused by using this query.

```
INSERT INTO `book`(`book_id`, `book_title`, `isbn`, `ean`, `book_image_url`,
    `book_author`, `book_description`, `category_id`, `book_type`, `addedBy`, 
    `addedWhen`, `modifyBy`, `modifyWhen`) 
    VALUES (NULL,'abc',123,,'http://www.example.com','xyz',,'1',,'admin',
    2008-06-08,NULL,NULL)
```

I have allowed `NULL` for `description`, `ean` and for the `book_type` column and also set `NULL` as the default value but this query is not working. But if I fill them i surprised that the query is executed.

What's going on?

Comment: Do you get an error? If so, what is it? If not, what does happen?

Comment: do you get any error messages? btw, you have a couple og ,,. Right after 'xyz' and after '1' you have some empty ,,

Comment: put empty string '' between commas. ie ,, replace with ,'',

Comment: ,'xyz',,'1',,'admin'  what goes here <------ ,,

Comment: i got this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''http://www.example.com','xyz',,'1',,'admin',2008-06-08,NULL,NULL)' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `book`(`book_id`, `book_title`, `isbn`, `ean`, `book_image_url`,
    `book_author`, `book_description`, `category_id`, `book_type`, `addedBy`, 
    `addedWhen`, `modifyBy`, `modifyWhen`) 
    VALUES (NULL,'abc',123,'','http://www.example.com','xyz','','1','','admin',
    2008-06-08,NULL,NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not put empty values like for the "ean" column in your example :

```
NULL,'abc',123,,'http://www.example.com'
```

The part between 123 and the URL should not be empty, but replaced with a NULL or an empty string, depending on what you want. Otherwise, it's a SQL syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

For some fields you are not passing any values

```
INSERT INTO `book`(`book_id`, `book_title`, `isbn`, `ean`, `book_image_url`,
    `book_author`, `book_description`, `category_id`, `book_type`, `addedBy`, 
    `addedWhen`, `modifyBy`, `modifyWhen`) 
    VALUES (NULL,'abc',123,'','http://www.example.com','xyz','','1','','admin',
    2008-06-08,NULL,NULL)
```